# Windows hangs on startup

Tags: windows-xp

I got in to work this week to find four windows xp computers all having the same problem - they are all hanging on the windows loading screen (the one with the logo and the green progress bar).

The only thing I could think that would cause this to happen on all of them at the same time are bad windows updates.

Can anyone shed some light?

Edit: some further details:
CAN get to safe mode.
System restore DOESN'T help.
HDDs are ok.
All were working fine last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they all the same spec?

Do you have other machines with the same spec?

If you do, take a Hard Drive out of a malfunctioning machine, try it in a working machine, and vice-versa.

Is there another piece of software installed on those machines but not on other machines, that may have updated and borked them?

Is there a specific piece of hardware common to the faulty machines but not to other machines in the office?

Can you virus scan the Hard Drive of one of the affected machines?

Comment: The machines are of different specs. There is no hardware or software that is unique to them - they are fairly standard office machines, mainly used for MS Office. Haven't tried swapping out HDs.

Virus scanning as I type. Clean so far...

Comment: I've enabled boot logging. 

Everything loads up until...

"Loaded driver kmxstart.sys
Did not load driver ACPI Uniprocessor PC"

after that it goes in to a loop of the following:

"Did not load driver LogMeIn Mirror Driver
Did not load driver Audio Codecs
Did not load driver Legacy Audio Drivers
Did not load driver Media Control Devices
Did not load driver Legacy Video Capture Devices
Did not load driver Video Codecs"

Comment: @Mr_Chimp: It looks as if a media player of some sort is not working correctly. A google search for "kmx media player" gave me http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/ - could you check if that has been installed, and if so uninstall it from safe mode?

Comment: kmxstart.sys is the driver for CAs HIPS component. Has there been an update or a change to the security suite?

Comment: Pulse: The CA security suite is due for renewing on the 21st. It says that that has loaded though. I would have though it would be the "ACPI Uniprocessor PC" that is not working...?

Comment: Well I booted into Safe Mode, uninstalled CA security suite and rebooted. Everything now works. Reinstalled CA and seems to still work. Kind of ironic when a program designed to keep your computer running stops your computer from running. Thanks for the pointers, guys.